# What is the difference between using "nbtstat -a IP" and "getmac /s IP"?

Tags: windows, networking, java, tomcat

when trying to retrieve the MAC of a remote client connecting to a tomcat server running in a intranet, I would like to know which of these two is more suitable for this scenario. running nbtstat has some issues with finding the right nbtstat.exe in devices that run windows server 2008(systemwow64 )devices. I would like to understand their basic ideas so that i can choose the right one between these two.

EDIT 1: Some background on the use case.
   The basic idea is to pull the mac address of all the devices that access an application running in a tomcat server(server is local to an organisation., meaning it will serve only intranet users) Once the request is received from the client, the client's IP is read from the request headers and the same is used to find the MAC of the client.
                      Is the above said method acceptable according to the best practices, what are the shortcomings of the same. Where and when will it fail(across networks)? Is this a sound method for getting the MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

**nbtstat -a IP**  would retrive the NETBIOS name for the given IP Address. while
**getmac /s IP** would return the MAC address of the given IP.